# Chrome OS + VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: google-chrome, virtualization, virtualbox, google-chrome-os

I can't install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in the latest build of Google Chrome OS. When I run the installer, I get the following error:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.1.8 Guest Additions for Linux.........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.1.8': Read-only file system
tar: /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.1.8: Cannot chdir: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What do I do now? Can I mount the filesystem in read-write mode? Does the Lime build support the guest additions? I'm using the Vanilla build.

Host OS: Mac OS X Lion (10.7)
Guest OS: Google Chrome OS Vanilla from http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/
VirtualBox version: 4.1.8

Comment: Which version of hexxeh builds are you using?

Comment: Here is a tutorial I've wrote with a step-by-step video screencast + a version that will work for you :) http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/

Comment: @Ido I'm using the Vanilla builds. Read carefully: I can't install the _guest additions_. The OS is working fine.

Comment: Sorry... I've missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So someone on the VirtualBox IRC channel irc://chat.freenode.net/#vbox told me that the guest additions won't work on Chrome OS.

After trying the suggestion from @sarnold, running `mount -oremount,rw /`, I was told

```
Unable to determine your Linux distribution
```

Comment: That sounds like a very large cop-out, since ChromeOS isn't much veneer over Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try remounting the filesystem as read-write, the command is:

```
mount -oremount,rw /
```

But there might be a good reason for `/` to be mounted read-only. I doubt the VirtualBox guest tools *care* where they are installed, so if you just unpack the archive using `tar` or `ar` or whatever is necessary, you can probably install them somewhere that *is* mounted read-write and configure them appropriately.

Comment: Remounting worked, but installation still fails. Someone on [VirtualBox's IRC channel](irc://chat.freenode.net/#vbox) told me that the guest additions don't work on Chrome OS. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using dev mode, I was able to run a parrot os vm with qemu and kvm on a pixelbook. I used the change kernel flags script from crouton repo, then installed qemu and kvm packages normally for my debian 9 crouton chroot. Virt manager doesn't work, but I can make a hard drive image with CLI and boot up a vm with CLI and it all works, albeit it is a bit slow even with kvm. Probably cause even a pixelbook has low resources compared to a normal laptop.